# Считать массив байтов с нужной позиции

Tags: android, файлы

Имеется файл с примерно таким содержимым

```
  {"id":"312312sc3","Name":"mynames","key":[1,0,9,118,3,115,3,15,127,4,117,116,0,112,117/*......*/]/*....*/}
```

Как можно вытянуть из файла нужное количество "значений" из поля key ?

Мой код при вытаскивании ключа считает каждый символ байта за отдельный байт, запятую тоже как отдельный байт и из-за этого с неправильно позиции неправильное кол-во символов считывается.. Файл размером более 10 мб..

```
   private byte[] спарситьКлючЧатаИзФайла(Context ctx, String FileName, int strLength, int ТочкаНачалоКлючаВФайле, int ПозицияНачалоОставшегосяКлюча)
{ //

    byte[] буферДляСчитыванияКлюча = new byte[strLength];
    byte[] размерПропуска = new byte[(ТочкаНачалоКлючаВФайле + ПозицияНачалоОставшегосяКлюча)];

    String[] БуферДляХранения = new String[strLength];
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStreamChatKey = new FileInputStream(new File(ctx.getFilesDir() + "/ChatInfo/" + FileName));

        inputStreamChatKey.read(размерПропуска);
        inputStreamChatKey.read(буферДляСчитыванияКлюча);

        inputStreamChatKey.close();
    } catch (Exception g){
        Log.i("MyLogIlnar", "Ошибка СпарситьКлючЧатаИзФайла* " + g);
    }



    return буферДляСчитыванияКлюча;
} //
```

Comment: Идентификаторы в кириллице это "пять"...

Comment: ИМХО. Возможно он хотел этим показать, что он имел ввиду, т.е. это код для вопроса, а так он использует латиницу.

Answer (score 2):

Очень похоже, что ваш файл, это Json файлик, если это так, то всё довольно просто, можете посмотреть решение для чтения массива в этом примере на офф. сайте **http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html** Соответственно далее вы можете после получения массива прочитать нужно количество элементов из массива. Даже если это и не Json файл я рекомендую вам всё же сделать по данному примеру, вполне может получиться

Comment: ПРи использовании Json parsera для того чтобы вытянуть массив опять таки нужно будет использовать цикл... а цикл будет выполняться очень долго..

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что выполняться будет долго. Вам нужно решение более быстрое, чем то, что давно уже придумано? Возможно оно есть, но если ваш файл - Json, то более адекватного и быстрого решения явно нету, иначе оно бы уже было. А если у вас встал вопрос о более быстром решении, то возможно что-то не так в вашей концепции, возможно вам необходимо изменить совсем другое.

Comment: Но если уж совсем хочется быстрее, то можете использовать функцию, которая позволяет считать массив данных из потока данных с определённого места, чтобы не считывать данные до **key:**, а потом удалить каждый 2 байт, который отвечает за запятую, но данное ускорение будет незначительным, я бы вам советовал использовать официальный способ

Comment: Приведу вам более понятный пример. Если у вас есть учитель русского языка на станции МКС, который хочет кушать и вы доставляете ему еду по средством ракеты, то вместо того, чтобы ускорять и без того хорошую ракету на какие-то жалкие 2 м/с, возможно, имеет смысл работать этому учителю на Земле и для выполнения его обязанностей хватит онлайн трансляции?